# Why does proc arima with NoEst throw 'There is not enough data to fit the model' error?

Tags: sas, time-series

I am using proc arima in SAS 9.4 to produce a forecast using a previously calibrated model, but it is throwing an error as if it is trying to calibrate the model itself :

*ERROR: There is not enough data to fit the model*

sample data:

```
data inputs;
input x var1 var2 var3 var4 var5;
datalines;
  20    5   2   4   5   4
  25    12  56  13  44  4
  20    5   2   4   5   4
  25    12  56  13  44  4
  20    5   2   4   5   4
  25    12  56  13  44  4
   .    2   5   6   5   4
;
```

failing version:

```
proc arima;
  identify 
    data = inputs 
    var = x
    crossCorr = ( var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 ) 
    noPrint;

  estimate 
    p = 1 input = ( var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 )
    ar = 0.9
    initVal = ( 0.1$var1 0.2$var2 0.3$var3 0.4$var4 0.4$var5 ) 
    noint 
    noEst /* Using noEst so should not need to do any estimation and short data-set should not be a problem */
    method=ml 
    noprint
;

  forecast lead=1 out=outputs noOutAll noprint;
quit;
```

If I remove the final variable from the model, it works fine:

```
proc arima;
  identify 
    data = inputs 
    var = x
    crossCorr = ( var1 var2 var3 var4 ) 
    noPrint;

  estimate 
    p = 1 input = ( var1 var2 var3 var4 )
    ar = 0.9
    initVal = ( 0.1$var1 0.2$var2 0.3$var3 0.4$var4 ) 
    noint 
    noEst /* Using noEst so should not need to do any estimation and short data-set should not be a problem */
    method=ml 
    noprint 
;

  forecast lead=1 out=outputs noOutAll noprint;
quit;
```

I can also get it to 'work' by adding one more value to the data. However, this shouldn't be necessary when the model is already calibrated (using much more data).

I've checked the SAS documentation to see if there are any flags to prevent the unnecessary check that causes this error but none of them helped.

Comment: I can't tell from your code which variable represents time and how many previous periods you have in your data, but ARMIA requires a certain number of previous periods for forecasting, depending on the order or the model.  If I recall correctly A model of order (p,d,q) needs max(p+d, q+d+1) previous observations.

Comment: My sample data bit at the top has 6 previous observations.

I have gone for the simplest model here which is (1,0,0), so I should only need 1 previous observation as per your formula (there's a separate issue that SAS seems to need a minimum of 6 observations).

Comment: I don't think I need to provide a time variable since the model should behave the same whatever the time step is as long as it is a constant time step.

The limit it is applying is based on the number of predictor variables that I use, since if I remove one it works fine. But that check only makes sense if it is having to calibrate the model, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been provided on the SAS communities forum. It is known behaviour and so my uncommon use case is not supported. The only workaround would be to add some dummy data, but in my case with MA terms that would change the results.

[Response on SAS Communities](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Forecasting-and-Econometrics/Why-does-proc-arima-with-NoEst-throw-There-is-not-enough-data-to/m-p/292257#M1876)